# URL structure, the best way

Tags: html, url

Does someone know that what is the best way to structure a URL?

```
site.com/part2section3group2product1

site.com/part2-section3-group2-product1

site.com/part2/section3/group2/product1

site.com/part2_section3_group2_product1
```

From the Siyavash Hamdi research pages, I think the way is

```
site.com/part-2/section-3/group-2/product-1
```

Am I right with this way?

Comment: What do u mean about `structure a URL`?

Comment: Yes, for the research that I am making, it seems is the "/" way. So I thing the best way is "site.com/part2/section3/group2/product1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best structure for URLs is SEO-Friendly structure which is the 3rd one, I mean `site.com/part2/section3/group2/product1`.

In this case search engines can categorize your website contents easily.

For more information visit following links:

[A Guide to the Perfect SEO-Friendly URL Structure](http://seositecheckup.com/articles/a-guide-to-the-perfect-seo-friendly-url-structure)

[15 SEO Best Practices for Structuring URLs](https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls)

[SEO URL](https://moz.com/learn/seo/url)

Comment: From your suggestion pages, I think the best way is "site.com/part-2/section-3/group-2/product-1", did I get it right?

Comment: @AlêMoraes, In [Keep a simple URL structure](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en) google has a good recommendations for your question as well.